# Is it possible to make a new method on a standard nodeJS object such as "fs" using C++/napi etc?

Tags: c++, node.js, node.js-addon, node.js-napi

I'm interested in making my first native C/C++ addon for nodeJS.

Conceptually it's a filesystem method that acts on a path or a file descriptor and is closely related to `fs.stat()` and friends.

From reading the documentation and looking at N-API examples I can't see whether it's possible or definitely impossible to create a new method.

Does anybody know if this can be done or if I have to just make it standalone?

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to do this is to "wrap" the object you want to extend.

Basically make a new module "fs2" that passes through all the standard calls to "fs" that is `require`d by your new module, but also add your new calls, or replace the calls you wish to augment, with your N-API calls.

Code using your module would then only need to use

```
let fs = require("fs2");
```

instead of

```
let fs = require("fs");
```

I'm not sure if there are several ways to wrap a nodeJS module to achieve this, or if there is one clearly best way. I'm sure there are other SO questions covering all that.